# How to get Scilab 6.1.0 working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, java, scilab

I have installed clean Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS and installed Scilab from repository here with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

After installation I tried to launch it from GUI (*Applications → Other → Scilab*) - it does not start.
Then I tried to launch it from terminal with `scilab` command. Terminal output is as follows:

```
$ scilab
...
Scilab cannot create Scilab Java Main-Class (we have not been able to find the main Scilab class. Check if the Scilab and thirdparty packages are available).
```

so it can't find Java again. I reported [bug 1870813](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1870813) about this problem. But as usual there is no reaction from package maintainers.

What should I do to get Scilab 6.1.0 working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that Scilab is working normally in the Ubuntu 20.10, so one can download packages from it and install into the 20.04 LTS system:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/scilab
cd ~/Downloads/scilab

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-cli_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-data_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-doc-fr_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-doc-ja_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-doc-pt-br_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-doc_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-full-bin_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-include_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-minimal-bin_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab-test_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scilab/scilab_6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hdf5/libhdf5-103-1_1.10.6+repack-2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hdf5/libhdf5-hl-100_1.10.6+repack-2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libm/libmatio/libmatio9_1.5.17-5_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./lib*.deb
sudo apt-get install ./scilab*.deb
```

---

But anyway it is strange method, and the Scilab packages should be fixed on the repository level by its maintainers.

Answer (score 3):

Scilab package for Ubuntu 20.04 seems to be broken, but you can always directly run it from the source.

1. Download scilab from [scilab website](https://www.scilab.org/download/6.1.0/scilab-6.1.0.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz)

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.scilab.org/download/6.1.0/scilab-6.1.0.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

2. extract the archive

```
tar xf scilab-6.1.0.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

3. run the file

```
./scilab-6.1.0/bin/scilab
```

Note: If you get following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libscilab-cli.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

run this command, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217891/how-do-i-get-scilab-6-1-0-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
```

Comment: @karel I tried the above tar.gz download, but it did not seem to work on Ubuntu 20.04.1 current (14 Oct 2020) for the Scilab GUI.  Wait.  It takes quite a while for the Scilab GUI to appear on your desktop (using an electromechanical laptop harddrive, not a SSD, Intel I7 CPU, 16 GByte RAM).  Once it works, one can add (at least in MATE GUI) this scilab to the application pulldown menu, or to the desktop.