# How to get Scilab 6.1.0 GUI (not just CLI) working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without smashing other applications?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gui, scilab

There is a question:  How to get Scilab 6.1.0 working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? that shows how to install Scilab 6.1.0 from either the Scilab tar from Scilab or from Ubuntu 20.10.  The first one is for the CLI only -- I need the GUI.  The second one forces the replacement/deletion of numerous libraries as well as applications that I need (such as grace).  Is there any way -- without smashing other applications and staying with LTS only -- to get a working Scilab current GUI and CLI? (My understanding is that LTS is intended to be similar to Enterprise Linux whereas non-LTS is intended to be similar to Fedora -- I only used Scientific Linux -- a supported port of Enterprise from Fermilab/CERN -- until SL7 was the last distro -- there will be no SL8.)  Unlike the Scientific Linux Users list in which the detailed line-by-line CLI output or configuration file, when I attempted to do this same approach for this Ubuntu "list", a Ubuntu list moderator removed the detailed output, and thus no one on this list can tell me specifically what to do to correct the use of the 20.10 Scilab (e.g., without detailed information, one cannot make a proper detailed recommendation -- this field is supposed to be computer science and engineering or perhaps IT).  Is there a SNAP Scilab current GUI? Take care.  Stay safe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Scilab 6.1.0 working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260149/how-to-get-scilab-6-1-0-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyvenv vs venv vs python-virtualenv vs virtualenv and python 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603935/pyvenv-vs-venv-vs-python-virtualenv-vs-virtualenv-and-python-3) Try it with your project to test if you can get all the packages you need installed in a Python 3 virtual environment where they won't interfere with other installed packages (such as grace) that you need. Please comment if you need further help. Using a Python virtual environment for projects has become very common. PyCharm IDE creates a  Python virtual environment for each new project by default

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if there was a Python IDE that let you freely mix system packages and Python virtual environment packages in the same project and then specify which packages to pull from where in the system in case you have multiple versions of the same package installed in different locations? PyCharm can do this too with the help of Anaconda. I haven't seen this covered in Ask Ubuntu, but it is well covered in Stack Overflow. Please comment if you need help.

Comment: If you have any lists that you need to include in your question and can't for whatever reason please comment to me starting the comment with @karel with a link to the list at [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and I will take the appropriate action to add it to your question. If there's any content of any kind that you can't add to any of your questions like in Scientific Linux please comment to me and I will add it to any other question.

Comment: @karel https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QvWZSkN2ds/

Comment: Your test list works. Here is a [link](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to the usage page for how to embed the text into a question as formatted text. If there is no programming language the programming language should be specified as *none*.