# I can't install Scilab

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, scilab

I can't install Scilab.
When I ran `sudo apt-get install scilab`
there was output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 scilab : Depends: scilab-cli (>= 6.1.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: scilab-full-bin but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: scilab-doc (= 6.1.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu3) but 6.1.0+dfsg1-6build2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to solve this?
please help. :)

Comment: Read the error message. Install the packages `scilab` depends on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scilab [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/scilab) is from *universe* pocket. The repository should be enabled  and then Scilab may be installed by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

---

Also please note that Scilab is broken on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. See other [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1260149/66509) for [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1260150/66509).