# Scilab graphic window appear but it is blank, there is no plot (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: 20.04, graphics

PC specification:

- OS:Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Processor: Intel i3
- ram: 4 gb
- 1 Tb Hdd

i have installed three version of scilab 5.0 ,6.0.2 ,6.1 by following the procedure below:

1. download tar files from official website
2. untar them
3. type `./bin/scilab`

Inn these three scilab version , i get the same problem that graphic window appear which is completely blank , there is no plot
now how i resolve this

---

my PC graphic : Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

```
(base) vivek@vs~$ lspci | grep -Ei "VGA|3D|Video" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02) 
(base) vivek@vs~$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor 
Command 'glxinfo' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install mesa-utils 
(base) vivek@vs~$ lsmod | grep drm, 
(base) vivek@vs~$ vainfo 
Command 'vainfo' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install vainfo
```

```
(base) vivek@vs:~$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor 
## server glx vendor string: SGI client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI Vendor: Intel (0x8086) OpenGL vendor string: Intel

(base) vivek@vs:~$ lsmod | grep drm 
drm_kms_helper 217088 1 
i915 cec 53248 2 drm_kms_helper,i915 
fb_sys_fops 16384 1 drm_kms_helper 
syscopyarea 16384 1 drm_kms_helper 
sysfillrect 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt 16384 1 drm_kms_helper 
drm 552960 11 drm_kms_helper,i915

(base) vivek@vs:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0 
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7 
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0 
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0) 
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 20.1.1 () 
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints VAProfileMPEG2Simple : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileMPEG2Main : VAEntrypointVLD 
VAProfileH264Main : VAEntrypointVLD 
VAProfileH264Main : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP 
VAProfileH264High : VAEntrypointVLD 
VAProfileH264High : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP 
VAProfileJPEGBaseline : VAEntrypointVLD 
VAProfileJPEGBaseline : VAEntrypointEncPicture
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP VAProfileVP8Version0_3 : VAEntrypointVLD 
VAProfileHEVCMain : VAEntrypointVLD 
VAProfileHEVCMain10 : VAEntrypointVLD 
VAProfileVP9Profile0 : VAEntrypointVLD 
VAProfileVP9Profile2 : VAEntrypointVLD
```

Comment: Couple of things fist do not use all caps like that. Second they have their own support https://www.scilab.org/services/user-support

Comment: do you think this is relevant

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the unnecessary capitalisation which hurts my eyes and make it difficult for people to read. If you left the `cap lock` on by mistake, you can use on online tool like https://convertcase.net/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Scilab 6.1.0 working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260149/how-to-get-scilab-6-1-0-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts). Alternatively, use [GNU Octave](http://octave.org). It has excellent syntax compalibility with Matlab and Scilab. `sudo apt install octave`

Comment: Please retry with `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./bin/scilab` . What is your graphics card? Please show the output of `lspci | grep -Ei "VGA|3D|Video"` , `glxinfo | grep -i vendor` , `lsmod | grep drm`, `vainfo` . Do you use real hardware or VM? Have you tried running Scilab 5.2?

Comment: N0rbert : thanks man

Comment: LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./bin/scilab     this is really help , now plots appear on graphic window

Comment: my PC graphic :  Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

Comment: Post the output to the question for remaining commands. [Edit it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1333764/edit).

Comment: (base) vivek@vs~$ lspci | grep -Ei "VGA|3D|Video" ##
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
__(base) vivek@vs~$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor ##

Command 'glxinfo' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mesa-utils

__(base) vivek@vs~$ lsmod | grep drm,
__(base) vivek@vs~$ vainfo ##

Command 'vainfo' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install vainfo

Comment: Please install both tools with `sudo apt install mesa-utils vainfo` and then run `glxinfo | grep -i vendor` , `lsmod | grep drm` and `vainfo` again.

Comment: just give me 2 minute

Comment: (base) vivek@vs:~$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor ##
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel

Comment: ______(base) vivek@vs:~$ lsmod | grep drm ########
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 i915
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   552960  11 drm_kms_helper,i915

Comment: ___(base) vivek@vs:~$ vainfo ######
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 20.1.1 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD

Comment: VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD

Comment: VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD

Comment: I would recommend to install the `i965-va-driver` package, then reboot and retry running Scilab.

Comment: i965-va-driver is already the newest version (2.4.0-0ubuntu1).
now restart

Answer (score 4):

As temporary solution you can force software video rendering by running Scilab with:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./bin/scilab
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the mesa drivers to this worked for me

```
## mesa drivers to correct plot issues with scilab 6x
# See --> https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-upgrade-mesa-drivers-radeon-nvidia-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa -y
RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 0):

using the environment variable `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=2.1` solved this problem for me at least, in Manjaro 2023-06-28.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that this works for me too in Debian 12:
in shell window:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=2.1 /bin/scilab
```

Also you can add it to your .bashrc:

```
gedit .bashrc
```

> #add folowing lines in this file:

> MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=2.1

> export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE

After saving the file either source it:

`source ~/.bashrc`

or reboot your system